# Problems with Interactive WebGL Globes with THREE.js and D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js

I want to make an interactive  globe 3D and I found this [site](http://www.delimited.io/blog/2015/5/16/interactive-webgl-globes-with-threejs-and-d3) that seems to be perfect to what I want, but I'm have some problems with the code.

1- I downloaded the source code but he don't open in my browser, it stop in the loading...

2- Are There best way to map the click on countries? The current code is using segments but if I want to click on some little country I will have to increase the amount of segments and this make some performance problems to some computers or cellphones.

Comment: You may have a look at [Cesium](https://cesiumjs.org/). It's an javascript framework for 3D globes and map. It might be a better choice than three.js in your case.

Comment: I just found this site is awesome:                          http://www.webglearth.org/api#TOC-WE.map-object

Comment: I will see the Cesium, seems cool